# How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, url-rewriting

How do I remove the `"index.php"` sticking out in every path in codeigniter somewhere in the center?
I want clean non `index.php-fied URLs`?

Comment: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you are using Apache place a .htaccess file in your root web directory containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Another good version is located here:

http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/

Comment: +1 for the link! Although had to tweak around a bit. got it with this --> 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: for some reason, i had to add a slash to the beginning of the RewriteCond.
    `RewriteCond $1 !^\/(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)`

Comment: For some reason, if you have index.php in the URL, it's not actually removed, it stays there and keeps working.

Comment: I used all the possible combinations and it's still not working for me!!!!! how did you get it to work??

Comment: Your Apache install needs to be configured to check .htaccess files - make sure that is the case.

Answer (score 61):

I had some big issues with removing the index.php. As a general rule the .htaccess below has been tested on several servers and generally works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

If you don't have any luck with that then the next step is to adjust your config file. Try some of the other URI protocols e.g.

```
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO

   $config['uri_protocol']  = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

If your still not having any luck try changing the rewrite rule to include your subfolder. This is often a problem if your using a temporary URL on a dev server etc:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subofolder1/subfolder2/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Just play around with these options, one should work. Also, make sure your index file is set to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: i thought your first code here was the solution for me but actually it is just sending any url like domain/* to domain/index.php it ism't sending domain/welcome to the welcome controller. was excited for a second then. trying the other suggestions now.

Answer (score 32):

Have the.htaccess file in the application root directory, along with the index.php file. (Check if the htaccess extension is correct , Bz htaccess.txt did not work for me.)

And Add the following rules to .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then find the following line in your application/config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's it, it worked for me.

If it doesn't work further try to replace following variable with these parameters  ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: thank you , i have been failing in this for long time dunno why but ur way worked like butter :D

Comment: Thanks. It's works. BTW, I needn't change config.php.

Comment: Thanks, this one helped me, I used PATH_INFO with WAMP

Answer (score 21):

Have a look in the `system\application\config\config.php` file, there is a variable named `index_page`

It should look like this

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

change it to

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Then as mentioned you also need to add a rewrite rule to the `.htaccess` file

Note: in CodeIgniter v2 this file was moved out of the system folder to `application\config\config.php`

Answer (score 9):

I found that I was not changing **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All** in my virtual host file at **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All    <---- replace None with All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All   <---  replace None with All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i got that AllowOverride None too, now it works !

Comment: The blog is gone now, and I would very much have liked to read it. None of these solutions are working for me...

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /codeigniter/index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

> after changing RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] with the project folder name "codeigniter".its working for me. Thanks guys for your support.

Answer (score 6):

> Step 1 => Place your .htaccess file in root folder where application and system folders exist.
>
> Step 2 => If your web path using sub-folder like - yourdomain.com/project/ - then use following code in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /project/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

> If your web path using root-folder like - yourdomain.com - then use following code in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried using the first of the above examples works only on my root but not on form loads etc will still try to use index.php in urls I will play around and come back to this if I can firugre it out

Comment: Thanks @Vinod.I was going crazy with this problem.I have been searching on the net for so long, tried various solutions but they never  worked until i came across your solution.Now my CI project is working and it has given me NEW HOPE to move on with CI.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Just thought i might add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

would be the .htaccess and be sure to edit your application/config.php variable in the following manner:

replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = “AUTO”
```

with

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI”
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have enabled `mod_rewrite` (I hadn't).
To enable:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also, replace `AllowOverride None` by `AllowOverride All`

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Finaly...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

My .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[assets/css/js/img]|robots\.txt)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Another module I needed to enable was `actions`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419757/how-to-get-htaccess-files-working-with-apache-virtualhost/14481297#14481297

Answer (score 4):

Solution tested on localhost as well as on real domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `mod_rewrite` as instructed in [this tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) from the CI wiki.

Answer (score 3):

This is an .htaccess for one of my CI projects:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectFolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The last line should give you what you need, though you may or may not need '/projectFolder' depending on how your folder structure is set up.

Answer (score 3):

As an .htaccess file, a good option is to use the one provided by the [Kohana Framework](http://kohanaframework.org/):

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

It's a well thought out .htaccess that just works.

Answer (score 3):

There are two way to solve index.php in url path for codeigniter

1:In config/config.php
Change code :

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

2:Create .htacess in root path if not created,Copy the following code:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Save it and then check in your Apache Configuration rewrite_module OR mod_rewrite is Enabled.If not then please enabled.
(Best Approach)!

Comment: This is correct and straight from the CodeIgniter docs. I also using this method.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this on apache2 on many different hosting and it works great.

Use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Be sure you have `enabled mod_rewirte` with a `phpinfo();`

Then do this in config/config.php:

```
$config['index_url']    = '';
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

If it doesn't works yet, try to change the `$config['uri_protocol']='AUTO'` to one of the listed inside `application/config/config.php` file on line 40/54:

Sometimes I used : `REQUEST_URI` instead of `AUTO` or `"QUERY_STRING"` for goDaddy hostings

Answer (score 2):

Look in the `\application\config\config.php` file, there is a variable named `index_page`

It should look like this

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

change it to

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Then as mentioned you also need to add a rewrite rule to the `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux and using apache2 server then we may need to override apache2.conf file also beside changes on .htaccess file. Find apache2 configuration file on **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** .

Search Directory /var/www/ Change **AllowOverride None -> AllowOverride All**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 :**

Add this in htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

**Step 2 :**

Remove index.php in codeigniter config

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Step 3 :**

Allow overriding htaccess in Apache Configuration (Command)

sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
and edit the file & change to

```
AllowOverride All
```

for www folder

**Step 4 :**

Enabled apache mod rewrite (Command)

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

**Step 5 :**

Restart Apache (Command)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Place a .htaccess file in your root web directory

Whatsoever tweaking you do - if the above is not met - it will not work. Usually its in the System folder, it should be in the root.

Comment: After spending couple of hours, I read this and found my mistake.

Comment: I also spent at least an hour because of this "little" trick. By default, the .htaccess files comes in `application` directory instead of root.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the index.php from the url as required:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots  \.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use these lines in `.htaccess` file; which I place in root folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then I can access http://example.com/controller/function/parameter

instead of http://example.com/index.php/controller/function/parameter

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you
paste this code in application folder in .htacess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value short_open_tag 1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one did me the complete magic:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

as well as this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

where the folder is the name of the subfolder if this codeigniter application is hosted as a subdomain
e.g domainname/folder/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Copy past following code in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Foldername of your ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```