# CodeIgniter - How to hide index.php from the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

This is what my `.htaccess` looks like. The `.htaccess` is sitting in `/www/scripts` directory which is the parent of codeigniter's `system` directory and which also contains `index.php`. I have enabled `mod_rewrite` in my Apache 2.2.x. This is on Ubuntu 9.10 server.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path), but it does not work. Is there anything I need to do in apache2, any specific configuration so that this works?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: what happens when you visit your site without index.php? what errors do you get?

Comment: Try these links, it may help your question: [http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/153950/](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/153950/) [http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/153372/](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/153372/)

Comment: If you *just* enabled mod_rewrite, then you may simply need to restart your server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i hope u have enabled mod_rewrite in ur server

Comment: yes i have enabled mod_rewrite, i think i made some progress, but now i get this error in apache error log, if .htaccess is enabled

"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error"

Comment: you might want to check this as corrent answer. it will b easy for other users.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

... means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then procede to the rewrite rule below

Answer (score 3):

Just toss the following code into your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution simply drop in root.

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score -2):

[CodeIgniter User Guide on URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)