# jquery.ajax in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, controller

I am having a problem in implementing `jquery.ajax` in codeigniter. I want to send the control to a specific function of a controller. I am setting the url in my javascript function like this

```
var url='<?php echo('First/index');?>';
var ajaxoptions={url:url,success:submit_ajax_response};
```

`First` is my controller and `index` is my function where I want to send the control. When I click on the event on which it is called the following url is formed

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/First/index
```

The URL is fine but it is generating the error of `404`. I have done such kind of operations various times in `zendframework` but unable to accomplish this job in codeigniter. I have noticed one thing that if I add `index.php` in the url it works fine. By adding index.php the url becomes like

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/First/index
```

I am astonished how to remove index.php from route file. I have only two lines in route.php file

```
$route['default_controller'] = "First";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I have already made my controller as the default controller.
 Am I doing correct? What is the problem and how to accomplish this job`

Comment: The URL is NOT fine if it is generating a 404.  What happens when you go to that URL in your browser?  If the problem is your ajax request, you need to post that code also.

Comment: @Calving Froedge I have noticed that If I include index.php/ in my url it works fine. How to remove index.php from route?

Comment: @Calving Froedge. Dude please see my edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check a couple of things.  First, in /application/config/config.php make sure index file is set to this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Second, make sure you have correct .htaccess.  This should be at the root of your public directory (same place as your index.php):

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options FollowSymLinks

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Calving Froedge. Thanks dude this is what I want to accomplish.... +1 for your well explained answer

Answer (score 3):

I notice the part that is missing form your URL is the "index.php" thing that CodeIgniter has.
Change your code to this: (You need URL helper, so load that before this):

```
var url="<?php echo (index_page() . 'First/index');?>";
var ajaxoptions={url:url,success:submit_ajax_response};
```

index_page returns your site "index" page, as specified in your config file.

In order to remove index.php from your CodeIgniter links see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path).

Comment: He should not have to add index.php to the route to get it to work unless he has not removed index.php from route.

Comment: @Calvin Froedge: that's why I echoed index_page(). If he has removed the index.php with mod_rewrite he must have changed `$config['index_page']` so everything should work in that condition too.

Comment: @Calving Froedge how to remove index.php from route file?

Comment: @Awais: You remove that with mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path

Comment: Change config /application/config/config.php so that this line:

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

is set to:  $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Use the .htaccess that Yasser linked to.

Comment: @Awais: Whether you remove index.php with mod_rewrite or not, in order for your code to just work right, it's a good practice to add index_page() as I said.

Comment: @Yasser Souri by adding index.php is creating so many problems. Like if I made a directory at root like `js` for javascript files it creates problem in urls of accessing any file in my generated directory

Comment: @Awais: No that is not correct. you can still access all your JavaScripts just fine.

Comment: @Yasser Souri I have visited your provided link to remove `index.php` through `.htaccess` but it is still having same problem. I want to remove `index.php

Comment: What is the problem? You should do two things. First the .htaccess thing. Second you should change your `$config['index_page']` to empty string.

Comment: @Yasser Souri Thannks dude. +1 for your nice explaination