# Login url redirects to home page after hiding index.php using htaccess in codeigniter - [Codeigniter url redirection issue]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am developing a shopping cart site using Codeigniter Gocart script. I hid index.php using htaccess. When I try to login using **localhost/project143/secure/login**, it works fine and goes to login page. But when I try the login link in live as **hostname/projects/project143/secure/login**, it redirects to home page instead of login page.The login page with index.php in the URL (**http://hostname/projects/project143/index.php/secure/login**) is opening login page well. I've attached the screenshot of my issue and redirection code for clarification. Anyone knows this issue and fix ?

**.htaccess**

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /projects/project143/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Home Page:**
[image]
**Login Page with index.php included in URL:**
[image]
**Login Page without index.php in the URL:**
[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the rewrite base to just / ??

Comment: check your .htaccess  file code once it's redirecting when you are trying to remove index.php

Comment: can show the code in your htaccess file

Comment: @Venkat he already mentioned .htaccess code in question

Comment: hey sorry....i didn't remember try after removing the rewrite base in line in the htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is solution
[How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Try user unicorn's answer.it will work.