# How to get .htaccess files working with Apache VirtualHost

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, virtualhost

My problem is that my `.htaccess` file on my local server is not being read. The settings in the `VirtualHost` file seem to always take precedence.

I have tried the following:

- Enabled `mod_rewrite`
- Changed the `AllowOverride` to `All` but this causes a `HTTP Error 500 Internal server error`. I have tried it with various options but it always causes a 500 error.

I am using a VirtualHost file on Ubuntu which looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /web/website
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /web/website>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my `.htaccess` file under `/web/website` I have the following rules (which are not being read):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^facebookexternalhit
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ogtags.php?$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 401 /401
```

One thing I tried which did work was appending these rules directly into the VirtualHost file, but I would like my `.htaccess` file to work! Is that such a big ask? :(

**Edit:** So I looked in my apache `error.log` and it says `Invalid command 'Action', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` referring to my `.htaccess` file. There doesn't seem to be a module called Action which I can enable. Any ideas?

**Edit 2:** I noticed that my `httpd.conf` file is blank. Should this matter since I am using `VirtualHost` files?

Comment: I have tried commenting out those rules, but doesn't look like they were causing the issue. Any other suggestions? I think you are right though, it must be one of these rules which are wrong. I even tried commenting out all the rules and again it had no effect! So I don't know what else to try!

Comment: Hmm but these rules work fine on the live server, including the 404s. So there must be something else in my local apache setup which is wrong.

Comment: ``httpd.conf`` is meant to add user configuration and it is included in ``apache2.conf`` file . It is blank by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at my apache `error.log` I realised I just had to enable the Apache `actions` module:

> sudo a2enmod actions

And no more 500 Internal Server Errors!

Hope this helps somebody down the line :)

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `RewriteBase /`  directive

Add it after the `RewriteEngine` directive :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: This didn't change anything, still getting `HTTP Error 500 Internal server` :(

Comment: check the logs which are usually in ``/var/log/apache2/error.log``