# try to remove index.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove “index.php” in codeigniter’s path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

1.create an .htaccess file in codeigniter directory with the following code

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /ex/
     RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]
     RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|opensearch\.xml|favicon\.ico|assets|forums)
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
  </IfModule>
```

2.and change the `config['index_page']='index.php'`  to `config['index_page']=''`

but it is not working. My httpd.conf(/etc/apache2/) is blank

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled **rewrite_module** on your Apache modules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ex/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```