# CodeIgniter URL routing doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. And I am having trouble removing the "index.php" from my codeigniter site URL.

My .htaccess files looks like this, I have my code inside hmvcExample folder.

*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hmvcExample/

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

*

And my I have removed "index.php" from config.php as well. But I still get the following error when i try to load the site without "index.php"

***Not Found
The requested URL /hmvcExample/signup was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80***

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: I see a closing `</IfModule>` tag, but no matching <IfModule mod_rewrite>` in front of it.  If that's the case in your actual .htaccess file, you should probably fix that first.

Comment: I still struggle with htaccess too, but from the looks of that you're rewriting the base to hmvcExample then trying to navigate to hmvcExample/signup shouldn't you be trying to navigate to just /signup?

Comment: There was a mistake from my end when coping and pasting the .htaccess content. There is an opening <IfModule mod_rewrite> tag available at the top of the file.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` just below `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: yes I did try that too :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be one of the question should have been looking for - [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

And there is another `config` that you need to edit:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Change the line written above to the following:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

If you have done all of this, there still might be one issue left - `enable mod_rewrite`

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; is set, and mod_rewrite is enabled too.

Comment: @TharakaAbeyratne Are other websites on your server working? Was this site working before you introduced the `.htaccess`

Comment: Hey I was able to fix it just now. I had to allow directory listing (I think that's what it's called.) in etc/apache2/sites-available and open the "default" file and set "AllowOverride none" to "AllowOverride All". Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

MAKE sure you have `AllowOverride All` set up in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (centos apache 2.2)

config:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```