# remove index.php from codeIgniter path

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with removing the `"index.php"` from my URL in CodeIgniter.

I tried as to change my .htaccess file to :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also tried to change `$config['index_page']` to `''` and to change `$config['uri_protocol']` to `'REQUEST_URI'` but it won't work.

I've also added these lines to `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` :

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

bu it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You'll find other solutions here: [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)