# Codeigniter 2.1.x + Smarty 3.1.x Integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I have follow http://searchdaily.net/codeigniter-2-smarty-3-integration/ that tutorial for integrating Smarty 3.1.14 to CodeIgniter 2.1.3, everything is working perfectly except for my links, when i try to navigate between my smarty files  it goes to ex:  http://local.host/project/index.php/Smartytest <- what i need to do is to avoid the index.php and just enter  as //local.host/project/Smartytest

in my test it says:

$SCRIPT_NAME is /cismarty-new/index.php

I just want to hide index.php so i can do /cismarty-new/Smartytest for example instead of /cismarty-new/index.php/Smartytest

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcodeigniter%5D+remove+index.php

Comment: not a duplicate its not the same problem, i've integrated CI + Smarty, with codeigniter the index.php doesnt appears, i can go to localhost/site/welcome and it works fine, but when i try with Smarty i have to put localhost/site/index.php/welcome to display it that is the real problem

Comment: Have you try set `index_page` config in **config.php** ?

Comment: Note: your `SCRIPT_NAME` value is normal and it will not change anyway.

Comment: yes i tried index_page in config.php, default is $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; i removed index.php and rename it and it doesnt work

Comment: http://www.blacklyontech.com/cismarty-new.rar

Comment: go to localhost/cismarty-new  then go to localhost/cismarty-new/index.php/testsmarty   thats the problem

Comment: i don't see your `.htaccess` file and you told me it's not a duplicate.., have you create one to remove index.php in CI URIs ?

Comment: when i create a view with CI it remove the index.php but when i create a view with Smarty it only work if i first type /index.php/example

Comment: Please set an .htaccess file with right configurations for CI and tell me after that. See my first comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503333/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-path <- That one worked! The Fifth Link of url you gave me.. Thanks lighta for guiding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using .htaccess ?

if you have not tried then do the fowling and see if it resolves the problem:

create a .htaccess file in the root of your folder (inside cismarty-new/), copy the code and save it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cismarty-new
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

then open the codeigniter config.php and leave the $config['index_page'] blank:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

PS: Remember to check if you have Apache's "rewrite_module" activated, otherwise it will not work.