# Codeigniter HMVC without 'index.php'

Tags: codeigniter

I implemented the wiredesignz HVMC functionality in CI 2.1.7.

The only problem, is that, unlike the tutorial I followed(http://somethingstatic.com/setting-hmvc-codeigniter-2-1/), I have to add 'index.php' in my url:

how it should be according to the tutorial:

```
http://localhost/site/hmvc
```

What I actually have to call:

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/hmvc
```

How can I configure CI so the 'index.php' is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to do anything extra. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14439636/1056620) will help you to get this thing done. Just normal procedure. I done multiple times with the same one.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it was a general CI type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
//user following code in your .htaccess file to remove index.php from url.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```