# Why is this .htaccess file mod_rewrite not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using MAMP and CodeIgniter.
The root of my website is: /Users/Roy/Websites/CodeIgniter-3.0.2
In the Websites folder I also have some other project but I don't think that matters. Here is the apache httpd.conf file: http://pastebin.com/Am0ew0C0

In my .htaccess file I'm using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule authz_core_module>
   Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
   Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

the .htaccess file is located at: /Users/Roy/Websites/CodeIgniter-3.0.2/.htaccess
I have no idea why the mod_rewrite isn't working, it's supposed to eliminate the use of index.php in the url because the URL I have to use now is: http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.2/index.php/about

And I would like that to become: http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.2/about PHP version 5.6.10 is used. **the .htaccess file is not being read by apache, that is the problem here, how to fix it?**

Comment: What message do you get when not using index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, there is no need to mess with the httpd.conf with MAMP installed. Simply get CodeIgniter and place it in the htdocs folder inside MAMP. After that create a .htaccess file inside the CodeIgniter folder (not the application folder inside there) and use the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /ci/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you have clean URL's and no longer need to use /index.php/about but can just do /about.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe from the fact of what you set your document root to `/Users/Roy/Websites/` in your httpd.conf file. Personally I would use `virtualhosts` if you plan to have multiple websites so that each one can have it's own `.conf` and you can set the Document root specifically for each site.

Anyway, so right now your `CodeIgniter-3.0.2` is a subfolder of `Websites` which is your document root. So most likely you're having a problem with the rewrite base.

If you have your files and .htaccess in the codeigniter folder, your .htaccess will need to look like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter-3.0.2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however when I paste everything in the .htaccess file and restart MAMP to be sure I still get the same thing.

When using http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.2/index.php/about I see my webpage but when I use http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.2/about I get the default not found page from CodeIgniter, here is an screenshot: http://imgur.com/65H4mxu

Comment: Did you update your CI config to this `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Try making the rewriterule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CodeIgniter-3.0.2/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: Still the same page not found after restarting MAMP, it seems like it doesn't even read this .htaccess file maby I should check the errrorlog?

Comment: Check the error log, also put in random text at the top of your .htaccess file. It it doesn't give you a 500 error it's not reading it.

Comment: I don't see anything special in the error log, here is a screenshot to be sure. The caught SIGTERM is caused by MAMP shutdown. http://imgur.com/tZxCo22 and when I type some random text in the .htaccess file it gives no errors at all, not when loading the webpage or in the error log.

Comment: Yeah it's not enabled somewhere. Do you have any other conf files configured for your website? It appears AllowOverride All is set

Comment: Yeah AllowOverride All is set I believe, there are quite alot of <directory/> settings in the httpd.conf file, maby that's a problem. I didn't change anything in here except the standard root folder. I changed that from Users/Roy/Programs/MAMP/htdocs to: /Users/Roy/Websites.

Here is another pastebin of the current settings in the httpd.conf file: http://pastebin.com/rNFg7Rvp

I don't think I have another httpd.conf file, except the mac standard ones ofc but I think that's turned off in /etc/private/apache2/httpd.conf and /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /Project_Name
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input russel, however the entire .htaccess file isn't being read for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It look like file permission issue. check out the properties of your .htaccess file and change the permission.

The try with this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

for more try http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess could be very frustrating. take a lot at what really works

1.Your .htaccess should look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /booking/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

2.Replace line 3 with the root directory name of your project, in my own case 'localhost/booking/'

3.Copy the .htaccess file from the application folder to the root directory. This means that you will now have to instances of .htaccess file in you entire project.

4.in your config.php , Base url should look like this in my own case

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/booking/'
```

5.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

6.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

7. turn on Mod-rewrite in your httpd.conf file by removing the # preceding this line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I hope this solves your problem