# Remove index.php in codeigniter on ubuntu using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Using Apache2 installed on windows 7, I use the htaccess configuration below to remove the index.php from codeigniter url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Could someone please tell why the configuration above does not work on ubuntu. 
I have enable mod rewrite using **sudo a2enmod rewrite**. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Comment: No error except I have to add index.php before controller before it can work. example: http://site.com/login will not work but http://site.com/index.php/login works. What is weird is that, with the same configuration, http://site.com/login works perfectly on apache2 installed on windows 7

Comment: Did you change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`? https://drupal.org/node/134439

Comment: yes I did change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All, rebooted the server but still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the ubuntu server is setup to pass PATH_INFO, meaning you don't need the query string. You can probably just remove the `?` from your rule and it should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
# no query string ----------^
```