# How to get rid of index.php in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was creating my first codeigniter project. I like this framework very much. But is there anyway to remove **index.php** page from the url ? Beside .htaccess ? Like i using form helper class to generate form. with this code

```
<?= form_open('site/login'); ?>
```

And the URL came out

`<form action="http://localhost/index.php/site/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

It would be great if somebody share how to do it. Thanks

Comment: RTM http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: No it isn't possible without htaccess. Everything is routed through the index.php file. Without it, you can't use codeigniter. So it's not possible without url rewriting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible **without** .htaccess, but why havent you got access to this? you can put it in the directory of the `index.php` to have your desired effect.

Because I don't like dead links, I will quote the official documentation:

> ### Removing the index.php file
>
> By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
>
> example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article You can easily remove
>   this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an
>   example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which
>   everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
 RewriteEngine on RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] In the above example, any HTTP
 request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is
 treated as a request for your index.php file.
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @jcorry the answer is that it is not possible without the use of .htaccess, you are unable to rewrite a users url path and map it to a different url structure without it.

Comment: that's great, and a necessary PART of removing index.php from the URLs in the site...but the original question points to the URL produced in the action attribute of the form tag written by form_open(). There's no .htaccess trick that will cause form_open() to remove the index.php from the URLs it writes. For that, you must change the index_page item in the config array.

Answer (score 1):

That won't remove it from the output of form_open().

If you use .htaccess to reroute the requests, make sure you also set the index_page in your config file to an empty string.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

With my index_page config item set to '', the form_open() method doesn't put an index.php in the form action URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to 
index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

You may also refer the below links:

https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/

http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/