# Codeigniter routes 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a website on a local wamp server (I have used a virtual host setup).  However when I try to link to another controller on the site, I just get a 404 page (not codeigniters 404).  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but what I'm not quite sure.

If in the url I put the website.co.uk/index.php/aboutus I get the page (although it's not got any of my formatting there).

I'm trying to have links in the format: website.co.uk/aboutus

Here is my routes.php

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';

$route['(:any)'] = '$1';
```

Here is my controller that I'm trying to link to:

```
class Aboutus extends CI_Controller {

   public function index()
   {

    //  $this->load->library('parser');
    //  $this->load->view('header_view');
    //  $this->loadContent();

    //  $this->load->view('footer_view');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $data = array();
       $data["title"]  = "Our Story";
       $data["page_content"]    = "here is some page content";
      $this->load->view('aboutus_view', $data);

    }   
}
```

I am using the follow href tag for the link

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('aboutus'); ?> ">
```

In my config file I have

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Has anyone got any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the htaccess I was using was in the wrong directory... It was in the applications directory and it needs to be at the same level as the applications directory not within it!

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to achieve is, removing index.php from url, you don't need to write a routes. You will need to write an apache rewrite rule for that. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path) for that.

Comment: I have tried that but am still having the same issues.  I am wondering if it is something to do with my setup?  It seems such a simple thing to do, I have tried a lot of different posts suggestions to no avail.

Comment: does your webserver setup have url rewrite capability? I assume you have apache as wbeserver? Do you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled.

Comment: I have just double checked and mod_rewrite is installed and enabled and I'm still not having any luck.  Yes I am using apache as my web server.