# Codeigniter link according to function?

Tags: codeigniter

In my codeigniter code there is a php controller Product.

```
<?php      
  class Product extends CI_Controller      
  {          
    function index($product_id)          
    { 
        ......
       ....
    }
  }
```

what is the link of this function. I try `localhost/demo/product/index/2` here `2` is `product_id`,`demo` is `project_name` . But this link does not work?

Comment: try with `localhost/demo/index.php/product/index/2`

Comment: Do you have a custom htaccess that removes 'index.php' from the url?
If not, please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path

Comment: Either ask a clearer question with more info, or go over the CI docs and figure it out yourself... The only answer I can give you is: Yes, it does work.

Comment: give some more info on weather you got a -htaccess file to remove index.php from the url. Do other urls using codeigniter work?