# I want to remove index.php name from url

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the project I am setting the following code in config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] ='index.php?';
```

In .htaccess the following code is set:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The directory structure is:

```
site_name
----ci_folder
-------application
----------  controller
----------  view
----------  model
--------system
-------.htaccess
```

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path possible duplicate.

Comment: If you want to *remove* the `index.php`, then do `$config['index_page'] ="";`, and set `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12330034

Comment: it's not work..i'm taking CI dirctory structure inside another folder.i.e.site_name/ci_folder/