# Removing index.php from CodeIgniter 3 URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am attempting to remove the index.php from my CodeIgniter 3 URLs. Currently, all of my URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/Controller/function
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
http://example.com/Controller/function
```

I have followed along on the following article and Stack Overflow post, yet none of the answers I've found have worked for me:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html
- [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

My directory structure is set up as follows:

- /var/www/example

  - /application

    - (standard CodeIgniter application files... controllers, models, views, configs)
  - /public

    - /css
    - /js
    - /fonts
    - /images
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
  - /system

    - I haven't touched anything in this directory
  - .htaccess

Contents of /var/www/example/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Contents of /var/www/example/public/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Contents of /var/www/example/application/config/config.php (trimmed to what I've changed based on prior reading):

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; /* have tried AUTO as well */
```

For my Apache server, mod-rewrite has been enabled via:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

My virtual host file for this site is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your virtual hosts file and adjust the Options directive as needed.

```
    <Directory />
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/example/public">
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```