# Codeigniter url/links with mode rewrite htacess: object not found

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am working on project using codeigniter for the first time with bootstrap 3.

My application and system folder from CI is located outside my 'project.main' folder. Everything works fine until I try to use .htaccess in my project.

I am using an XAMPP server and I already loaded the rewrite module and as well as the AllowOverride All and restarted my server.
My url now looks like this 'http://localhost/project.main/' ..
 Now my question is since I already removed the 'index.php', my navbar links in bootstrap was like this
 '`<a href='<?php echo site_url("pages/view/about"); ?>`
but if I click it I am directed to the url
'http://localhost/project.main/pages/view/about' which gives me

> Object not found' error page.

But if I use `href=' <?php echo site_url("index.php/pages/view/about"); ?>` I am routed to the right page. 
Which is the right way of doing it? and under my config.php I have this `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI ';` is it necessary that `uri_protocol` match what is on the .htaccess under `RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI)..`?
What i read in github there are two versions of .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt mention changing index page to blank inside config.php ? In case of emergency I give you my simple htaccess. It works when moving application and system folders out of public.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Also try to switch uri_protocol option.

Here's the ultimate solution for index.php [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path) .

Comment: thank you for the response, yes i already set that. I tried several .htaccess setups and iam confuse which is which. So far these are some of the .htaccess i tried: https://gist.github.com/4226750 - and this is what i currently have, the first one. I just thought since i have two separate folders should i place the .htaccess in the main folder? or the folder that contains the system and application folders?

Comment: Awesome! i tried that short code of yours and it works. Thank you! and the other mistake i had was i placed the .htaccess in the second folder.  i already moved it in the first folder then.