# Removing index.php from url in codeigniter using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/user/main_page

how can you remove index.php from this url ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Answer (score 1):

Try this file. I use it in my projects

https://github.com/eborio/curso-de-codeigniter/tree/master/02-primeros-pasos

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the post that this question is ducplicated of.

[This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445432/3809894)

Sean Vieira's answer:

> If you are using Apache place a .htaccess file in your root web
>   directory containing the following:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
> ```
>
> Another good version is located here:
>
> http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Replace:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
to
$config['index_page'] = ""

 if it still not work try to replace:

 $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

for more details: http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/ check this