# Codeigniter URL case sensitive issue IIS(uppercase to lowercase)

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

http://localhost/projectname/

The above url works fine .

But if we input

http://localhost/PROJECTNAME/

it gives a "404 Page Not Found" error.

I just want to know how to convert *Uppercase* **PROJECTNAME** to *Lowercase* **projectname**.

I am using **php 5.4** along with **IIS 8.5**.
And I also want to get rid of **index.php**.
I need some help with the rewrite rule or routing or maping.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this might help you, http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Comment: @Raju..I am not using apache, i am using IIS

Comment: Post your web.config file content here!

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it by htacces only,
Best way is don't use localhost use virtual host
Use the ip directly ,you can get a bind pannel there you can set ip