# Codeigniter call Function in Controller without index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know there are so many posts concering that problem. I tried everything, but without success.

I use xampp v3.2.2 on my windows 10 machine. In my htdocs I got a project called mysite. In there I have codeigniter 3.0.3.

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'CI_home';
```

Controller CI_home.php:

```
class CI_home extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($lang = ''){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('language');
        $this->lang->load($lang, $lang);
        $this->load->view('view_home');
    }
}
```

When I call `http://localhost/mysite`, the page is shown correctly.

The problem is, when I try to `http://localhost/mysite/en` or `http://localhost/mysite/index/en` I received a 404 from xampp.

But if I try `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/CI_home/index/en` it works fine.

What I am doing wrong? How can I remove the "CI_home/index"?

`http://localhost/mysite/.htaccess:`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I already checked if the mod_rewrite is enabled.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance,
yab86

Comment: Add to your route.php `$route['(:any)'] = 'CI_home/$1';`

Comment: Thank you MAZux. I tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try to add the index method also, try: `$route['(:any)'] = 'CI_home/index/$1';`

Comment: Which one are you using wamp, xampp, lamp etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this htaccess below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure htaccess in your main directory.

Then set your base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Then remove index.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

> **Note:** Codeigniter 3 versions are case sensitive. **Make sure only the first letter upper case of class and file name**.

```
<?php

class Ci_home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
    }

     public function index($lang = '') {
       $this->load->helper('url');
       $this->load->helper('language');
       $this->lang->load($lang, $lang);
       $this->load->view('view_home');
     }
}
```

Then make sure file name is Ci_home.php

Then your default route should be

When using default controller make sure is the same name as the controller you choose.

[URI Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'ci_home';

$route['(:any)'] = 'ci_home/index/$1';
```

Comment: It was the problem with letter upper case. Thank you wolfgang1983!