# wamp server in not showing project in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp, wampserver

I am facing a issue while removing index file.

I put a .htaccess file in the root directory of project to remove index file but when I do this server doesn't show project on localhost.

Then I found there was a .htaccess file in application folder which has 'deny of all',I changed it to 'Allowoveride all' but still it is not showing me my project folder.

What I am missing? Please help me. Is there any configuration I am missing or something else?

Comment: post your .htaccess file

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911594/codeigniter-call-function-in-controller-without-index-php/34912617#34912617

Comment: Make sure you have enabled your Apache mod rewrite modules. In wamp. And make sure you have placed the htaccess file in main directory. **Not Inside Application Folder**

Comment: yes i have placed .htaccess file in main directory not in applicaation and apache rewrite_mod enabled and restart the browser. but i am still facing the same issue

Comment: Did you try the htaccess that is on my answer on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911594/codeigniter-call-function-in-controller-without-index-php/34912617#34912617 Also make sure your class and file name has first letter upper case only.

Comment: thanks a lot  @wolfgang1983...its now working but submit button is still not able to find the controller and method i am using CI 2.2.6

Comment: thanks again @wolfgang1983...i read your code deeply now i have solved all issue...you helped me alot...

Comment: did answer to this question worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess with this condition or send your htaccess here.

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

for me in local it showing complete list.

Thanks
Amit