# Remove index.php from url in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am doing a project in CodeIgniter 3. I need to remove `index.php` from url. For that help me to get `.htaccess` file for CodeIgniter 3 and also where to place this file.

This is my baseurl

```
http://cableandmedia.com/demo/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path, you should search it before ask a question

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate question, but [the answer is clearly spelled out in the CodeIgniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file) if you'd only bother to look.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update your htaccess file with the below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and in config file, please change base url with below code:-

```
$root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = $root;
```

Answer (score 14):

Place your .htacces file in the root directory and use the following code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Create `.htaccess` file at `root` of the project

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
</IfModule>
```

2. Remove index.php at the `root/application/config/config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3. If your server is new | your server rewrite mode was denied than Open Terminal  Connect Your Server Via SSH Type Below Code

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

After that please check `AllowOverride` Is `All` or not

```
<Directory “/var/www”>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

**File**: config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**File**: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**RewriteEngine** allows you to rewrite URL requests that come into your server and is based on a regular-expression parser.

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.php` make following changes.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And add `.htaccess` file in main project directory with following content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Here what I did,

I edited/create ".htaccess" to this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and "app/config/config.php"

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and "app/libraries/Template.php"

```
define("PATH", base_url()."index.php/");
define("BASE", base_url());
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a .htaccess file at the project's root and add the code below.

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2. In your config.php make the following changes.

```
$config['base_url']    = 'PUT YOUR BASE URL HERE';    
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. open your .htaccess file present in the root and add the below code :-
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


2. Now in your config.php file 
 update this line of code :- $config['index_page'] = '';
```