# Codeigniter 3.1.6 - How to remove index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on codeigniter 3.1.6.

I added the .htaccess file.
I also changed the `base_url` path to my project path, removed the `index.php` from `index_page` and changed the `url_protocol` to `REQUEST_URI`.

Still, while I am redirecting the url to any controllers method it throwing an error as '`The page you requested was not found`.'

I also searched and applied different .htaccess but its not working.
If I am addling `/index.php` at end of base_url then its working but its wrong though. It should work without index.php.Only 3.1.6 giving this issue.

note: codeigniter-3.1.4 is working properly only this version is giving an issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter 3 Remove index.php Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169545/codeigniter-3-remove-index-php-problems)

Comment: But not working according to that responses. That's why I posted here

Comment: Try the answer of this question. then let me know I will help you sure.

Comment: I tried just now. Still same issue

Comment: did you follow: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=remove%20index%20php#removing-the-index-php-file ?

Comment: yes, now its giving this error : Object not found @Vickel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256295/2588459

Is this helpful?

Comment: No, Actually Old codeigniter-3.1.4 is working properly only this version is giving an issue

Comment: @MohammedSabir can you also share your .htaccess code so that we can figure out if the issue is in your  .htacces file?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>` Here is the .htaccess code

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477720/remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-3

Comment: Nope  @YadhuBabu

Comment: whats your base url

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.6';` Codeigninter-3.1.6 is target folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change folder name `CodeIgniter-3.1.6` to `ci`

Set your `base_url` to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/
```

Use this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Awesome bro, it works. But it is all going on? Die to missing `RewriteBase /ci` ? For other version I havent use such line still they are working fine? How?

Comment: Awesome. The .htaccess file to edit should be the one in the root folder. Not the one in the application folder

Answer (score 2):

Use this script in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  # If your root folder is at /mypage/test1/
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /mypage/test1/index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
 # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
 # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

Remove `index.php` from `config.php`
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Not Working @Sunday

Answer (score 1):

1) Edit config.php

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
 $config['index_page'] = '’;
```

2) Create/Edit .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not Working bro. Already done that. Only this version giving an issue. I am using this version for first time

Answer (score 0):

1:Create .htaccess file in root directory not another project folder directory.

2:write or copy this code and paste it

```
 `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
              <IfModule>`
```

I hope this will work properly.
Go In Config file and make changed 
$config['url_protocol']='auto';

Answer (score 0):

Additional tip: make sure .htacces in the root folder not inside >application folder