# CodeIgniter htaccess: `[controller]/[function]/[argument]` not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi successfully removed the index.php in my url, however the `[controller folder]/[function]/[argument]` isn't working anymore

this is my htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've also changed this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

this is my config['base_url']

```
$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;
```

and I have changed my http.conf in apache
AllowOverride All

I've also restarted my xampp already, Cna anyone help me why the  `[controller folder]/[function]/[argument]` is not working?

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608887/codeigniter-3-1-6-how-to-remove-index-php-from-url/46615615#46615615) to the same QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your .htaccess script as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /codeigniter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it's not working :( , before, it says 404 page not found, now it says object not found

Comment: 404 was the .htaccess error but object not found it probably an error somewhere in controller or model

Comment: i tried this RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: and it works, however i don't want to kept on changing the RewriteBase when i wanted to change the file name of the system, can this be done?

Comment: this code of htaccess is used to remove the index.php from the URL, So in this case, we need to use `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: @domin0101 I also edited my answer for you, If its the exact answer that worked for you then please you can make it as accepted.

Comment: I used `RewriteBase /`  but the site went to the localhost/dashboard

Comment: No, I mean you also need to specify your directory name with it like  you did `RewriteBase /codeigniter`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

RewriteBase /[file name].

Answer (score 1):

use this to avoid changing your RewriteBase

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```