# How to remove File Extension (index.php ) from URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, godaddy-api

I'm unable to remove file extension from my URL

https://www.deemsolar.com/ar/index.php

This is the current URL of my website

I want to change this as https://www.deemsolar.com/ar/

Please Help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove index.php from url in CodeIgniter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477720/remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: make sure that in `config.php` file,

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs fully and clearly.
[codeigniter urls docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# For Index
RewriteRule ^index.extension?$ /index.php [NC,L]

# For Another Page
RewriteRule ^login.extension?$ /login.php [NC,L]
```