# routing issue in localhost in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have this URL: http://localhost/fixbud/ as my home URL. My page is rendering fine. But when I go to another link like: http://localhost/fixbud/answer_forum I get error 404.

Here are my routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "fixbudd";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['index'] = "fixbudd/index";
$route['answer_forum'] = "fixbudd/answer_forum";
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/fixbud/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Can you tell me the rules in routing URL and how to solve my problem?
I am using CI2

Comment: might be url rewrite issue

Comment: did you have added `htaccess` file?

Comment: sorry about that, i have edited my post and included my htaccess

Comment: can you access your url from here : http://localhost/fixbud/index.php/answer_forum

Comment: also check in your `application/config.php` file and  check `$config['index_page'] ` variable. if you have `index.php` then remove it

Comment: yes, i can. but i want to access my url without the index.php. how can i do that?

Comment: please check my above comment

Comment: $config['index_page'] = ''; it is set to empty string right now

Comment: now can you access?

Comment: $config['index_page'] = ''; and $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Comment: still error 404 in http://localhost/fixbud/answer_forum

Comment: replace your .htaccess with this and check
`RewriteEngine On`  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`   
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`  
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: same output, still error in my desired url without the index.php

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on                       
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: refer these links :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path

Comment: yes, i already saw them. but it doesn't fix my problem. like i stated in my post, http://localhost/fixbud/ is working, but when i change the url to http://localhost/fixbud/answer_forum it doesn't work.

Comment: @easydev can you add folder structure on your project ... need complete path to root folder

Comment: root->assets, appplication, system, user_guide, .htaccess, index.php.
root->application = cache, config, views etc.
root->application->view = my view files

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and added this to apache config solved it.

```
   <Directory "<to your project">

       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

       AllowOverride All

      Order allow,deny

      allow from all

      Require all granted

</Directory>
```

source http://acmeextension.com/remove-index-php-in-your-codeigniter-project/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the .htaccess file, I prefer making new .htaccess file for local env and add the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/fixbud/';`

This to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/fixbud/';
```

And your call is going to "fixbudd" controller and method "answer_forum";

Comment: still not working. when i enter http://localhost/fixbud/answer_forum in the url, still error 404 object not found. but http://localhost/fixbud still works.