# code igniter redirect page not working as expected

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, model-view-controller

```
if(){
redirect('Login');
}
```

I have a condition above that redirect the page to log in depending on some values. I can see in url that I get redirect because when I enter

`http://www.myapp.com` it changes to `http://www.myapp.com/Login`

Now In my route I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['Login'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

My Login  controller looks like:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('Login_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['title'] = 'GYM';
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

}
```

In my view I have

[image]

But why Im getting

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
www.myapp.com
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.7
```

I cant figure out where I got configuration wrong

`Update:`
change config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';//'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

accessing:

`http://www.myapp.com/index.php/Login`

Works but all the above does not. I not getting why

Comment: are you removing `index.php` from the url? by default codeigniter url will looks like `http://www.myapp.com/index.php/Login`

Comment: that I didnt try how to remove that one? @HastaDhana where should i check it

Comment: have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445432/8566549

Comment: @HastaDhana is there another reason? I tried above still I get the same thing.

Comment: Sorry it's just for information purpose. Are you planning to remove `index.php` or keep it in the url?

Comment: well Im not using it so I guess its ok to remove it I just want to run my app.

Comment: @HastaDhana when I access `http://www.myapp.com/index.php/Login` it works but all the above does not. I not getting why

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including below lines on the `.htaccess` at the root level of the codeigniter app folder :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I finally figure out can you include in your answer. TH .htaccess that should be edited is the one which is in level with the application not the one level with the view. I need to ad that one. Please add it as answer as you are the first one to answer it. I will accept it as the correct answer

Comment: happy coding mate

Answer (score 0):

change your value like following

```
$route['login'] = 'Login';

$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

if not work, replace this code in **htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: when I access `http://www.myapp.com/index.php/Login` it works but all the above does not. I not getting why. I tried your solution not working either