# Not removing index.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am sending form data (views to controller) but i want to remove index.php from url.  For this I removed index.php from config.php but it is not working for me.  How can I remove index.php from the url and post data without using index.php? Here is my code in views:

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/Home/login">  
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="name"id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input maxlength="10" minlength="3" type="password" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"required>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: using htaccess you can remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your helper calls from `action="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/Home/login"` to `action="<?php echo site_url('home/login')?>"` when you need a link to the controller. For static resources (css, uploads, etc), keep calling `base_url()`.

You'll also need to have `mod_rewrite` [properly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385) as suggested in the comments.

Comment: i tried but then form data not posting/hit on controller

Comment: @Dishakamboj so you are not reaching the controller at all? Looks like a `mod_rewrite` problem. For `Rewrite` to work in `.htaccess` you need at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your server config

Answer (score 0):

1)make .htaccess file and put this code

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2)change

```
 $config['index_page'] = ''; 

 remove index.php present in config.php file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click [here](https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-htaccess/) make the htaccess file in the root folder.

Now remove index.php from this line.

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/Home/login">
```

Answer (score 0):

create file .htaccess in your root system folder and add code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

then you can remove index.php in your code