# Remove index.php from codeigniter project on localhost and apache server

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I have a project in CodeIgniter that I am running on my local machine on LocalHost. I have to use `http://localhost/projectname/index.php/controller/function` to run my APIs. I want to access the same URL but without including `index.php` in the URL.

Earlier I had XAMPP installed and I was using its htdocs folder and everything was functioning as required. But now I have uninstalled it and manually set up Apache 2.4, PHP 8, and MySQL 8. After doing so, there is this issue.

I am new to both manually setting up servers and CodeIgniter. Please help me fix this and if possible give a reason why this happens, it will help me learn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Comment: @brombeer I have tried this solution but it is not working

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled in your Apache? Is `.htaccess` allowed?

Comment: @brombeer I know nothing about it. Maybe that's the issue. How to do it?

Comment: Have you searched this site already? Pretty sure there are answers on the topic

Comment: I searched a few articles and mod_rewrite was the issue. I fixed it now. Thank You : )

Comment: Nice, glad it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add a .htaccess in the root directory and then add the following rules to the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Then find the following file in your application. File Path is application/config/config.php. In this file find below the code

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Change that line as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Now try to open URLs without index.php.